# using the same '_form' for 'create' and 'update' in nesting resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

rails:

I have 'create' and 'update' using the same partial '_form'

but the url that the form should send to is different

I code generated by rails gives an @xxx as parameter to form_for

I guess rails will judge to send to 'create' or 'update' by whether the content is empty?

But I`m using a nesting resource.
rails seems not so smart to handle this.

So,what is my best practice?

put 'if' in _form?

create 和 update 同时使用一个局部模板 _form

但是表单提交的url不一样

rails自动生成的直接给form_for给了个@xxx做参数 我猜是按内容是否为空判断是create还是update的？

但是我的情况是个嵌套的资源

rails似乎没有聪明到这种程度？

那么我的最佳实践是什么？

在_form中写逻辑判断么？

routes:

```
        book_structures GET    /books/:book_id/structures(.:format)             {:controller=>"structures", :action=>"index"}
                        POST   /books/:book_id/structures(.:format)             {:controller=>"structures", :action=>"create"}
     new_book_structure GET    /books/:book_id/structures/new(.:format)         {:controller=>"structures", :action=>"new"}
    edit_book_structure GET    /books/:book_id/structures/:id/edit(.:format)    {:controller=>"structures", :action=>"edit"}
         book_structure GET    /books/:book_id/structures/:id(.:format)         {:controller=>"structures", :action=>"show"}
                        PUT    /books/:book_id/structures/:id(.:format)         {:controller=>"structures", :action=>"update"}
```

_form:

```
<%if (form_method == :post) %>
  <%using_url = book_structures_path%>
<%elsif (form_method == :put) %>
  <%using_url = book_structure_path%>
<%end%> 
<%= form_for(@structure,:url => using_url,:method => form_method) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a version of your code in English?  I can read the question but not the example.

Comment: Added some main code.Tell me if you need anything else. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
<%= form_for([@book, @structure] ,:method => form_method) do |f| %>
```

to build a form for nested resource.

Comment: @user1189356 `form_for nested resource' could be the keyword to find our the answer.

Comment: Sorry I made a silly mistake that instead of adding another comment, I edited your comment directly.

Comment: Oh it works
Seems I chose a wrong keyword to search,how idiot I am...= =b